# Ukrainian (uk) language support in xpages extension library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

### Ukrainian (uk) language support

I have a big problem with an application running on a `Domino Server 9.0.1 FP9` with the language support for ukrainian (`uk`):

[image]

[image]

I had no troubles on a  domino server 8.5.3 environment!

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem mentioned above doesn't break the application.

Therefore the best approach for me to handle this problem is **to ignore it**.